# How can I push all array variables of N arrays in just one array over an loop function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an problem to figure out how to write code in JavaScript for that:

1. i have many arrays -> 1 to N arrays like that

   ```
   let array_0 = ["a","b","f"];
   let array_1 = ["c","b","g","r"];
   let array_2 = ["a","b","f","2","43"];
   ..to N..
   let array_N = ["a","a","s","d"];
   ```
2. at next i need all the variables in just one array like that:

   ```
   let array_fin = ["a","b","f","c","b","g","r","a","b","f","2","43","a","a","s","d"];
   or over the console.log() -> 0: ["a","b","f","c","b","g","r","a","b","f","2","43","a","a","s","d"];
   ```

but over an loop function for all array_N's

I tried to do that over the map() function, but the map function gives me an array like that:

```
0: ["a","b","f"]
1: ["c","b","g","r"]
2: ["a","b","f","2","43"]
..
N
```

but that's not what I need and I couldn't figure out which command could do that.
I tried also an function like push(), but I could not figure out how to call that over an loop function to handle N array's.

Comment: You have all arrays nested inside a structure or they are holds on different variables?

Comment: @Shidersz i tried to set all names of all variables over an loop function in just one array, but i cant figure out which function i could take. because the problem is, if i try to set the push function over an loop with array_all (example array_all = ["array_0","array_1",...]) , they push just the names (array_0 -> N ) in the new array, not the variables

Comment: That's because you're using `""` characters around the variable names. Drop those, and you'll get the actual data inside one array. Like: `array_all = [array_0, array_1, ...]`

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher oh sure, but how, if i write something like that array_with_all_variables.push(array_all[i]) it doesn't work

Comment: @EduardTester you can do something like `array_with_all_variables.push(...array_all[i])` :D that spread syntax (`...`) is pretty fancy stuff

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher it's not an operator.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ok, "spread syntax" which is on the [`operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) page of the mozilla developer documentation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to type them all out, just make them global variables using `var` and join them using spread syntax `...array_N` and a `while`-loop:

```js
var array_0 = ["a","b","f"];
var array_1 = ["c","b","g","r"];
var array_2 = ["a","b","f","2","43"];
var array_3 = ["a","a","s","d"];
let result_array = [];
let i = -1;
while (window[`array_${++i}`] instanceof Array) {
  result_array = [...result_array, ...window[`array_${i}`]];
}
console.log(result_array);
```

And yes, this will work for 1500+ Arrays, too :)

Comment: your code is not really efficient, right? :D today i had a look at the consol.log of your code and it looks like your code would repeat the array twiche. so in the array are 32 values, which costs much time :D but again. thx to see an different kind of programming style

Comment: I assume `result_array = result_array.concat(window[\`array_${i}\`]);` will be alot faster.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `concat()` to merge all your arrays like this:

```js
    let array_0 = ["a","b","f"];
    let array_1 = ["c","b","g","r"];
    let array_2 = ["a","b","f","2","43"];
    let array_N = ["a","a","s","d"];

    let array_fin = array_0.concat(array_1, array_2, array_N);
    console.log(array_fin);
```

Comment: for example 1500 arrays?

Comment: @EduardTester really? 1500 unique variable names? If you've already typed that much then typing this should be easy for you.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it could be more then 1500. i need an loop function for that, because let array_fin = array_0.concat(array_1 ... array_N); doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `window` object in order to access global variables (i.e the arrays) and make a loop for concatenate they, as shown on next example:

```js
var array_0 = ["a","b","f"];
var array_1 = ["c","b","g","r"];
var array_2 = ["a","b","f","2","43"];
var array_3 = ["a","a","s","d"]; 

// Create the array of all arrays.

let numOfArrays = 4;
var array_all = [];

for (i = 0; i < numOfArrays; i++)
{
    array_all = array_all.concat(window['array_' + i]);
}

console.log(array_all);
```

Comment: Why not reduce your code to `let array_all = [...array_0, ...array_1, ...array_2, ...array_3];` if you're typing them out already?

Comment: @Shidersz you did a little mistake. it's not array_all = array_all.concat(window['array_' + i]);, because it will double the arrray values in it, but with array_all_2 = array_all.concat(window['array_' + i]); will the code work like a charm :)

Comment: @EduardTester I don't understand, the snippet is working right now. Actually, if I made that change you are suggesting the result would be incorrect. The `concat()` do not mutate (or changes) the original array, but returns a new array with the concatenation, so I need to do that assignation.

Comment: @Shidersz amazing you are right. its really different between snippet and own server, strange but i think thats just an little problem for all who try to understand the code :D

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). **Not recommend** to be used, since eval has security issues. Just for knowledge that this is also possible.

```js
let array_0 = ["a","b","f"];
let array_1 = ["c","b","g","r"];
let array_2 = ["a","b","f","2","43"];

const res = [];
for(let i = 0;;i++){
  try {
    const arr = eval(`array_${i}`);
    res.push(...arr.filter(a=>!res.includes(a)));
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

[Why not to use eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)

Comment: thx for the info, but i am a beginner. atm i dont care about security functions =/ i have also to read all functions from from the beginning to understand which do that what they do, but atm i am focused to understand the syntax of javascript. but i think that information was also for all who read that thread. right? right!? right, right!! :D